# How to import python files from a folder in main program in colab

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import a script python(for example sub.py) from a folder named subfolder to main program(script python named main.ipynb) but colab can not find that module and have an error.
Code for import sub.py in main program is  `from sub import func1,func2`
branch of program is
main.ipynb
subfolder
--sub.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from subfolder.sub import func1,func2
```

Comment: @kobi If this solved your problem, then please mark it as accepted answer.